# view doesn't get recomposes when mutable list changes

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have an application that has a statelist in the viewmodel. and i have function that adds a number in the list. when i click on a button, it adds the number in the list. but the changes is not getting reflected in another view.

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val viewModel by viewModels<MainViewModel>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {

                    Column {
                        Button(onClick = {viewModel.increaseCounter()}) {
                            Text("Increase counter")
                        }
                        CountView(viewModel.counter)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("CoroutineCreationDuringComposition")
@Composable
fun CountView(count: List<Int>) {
    var coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    coroutineScope.launch {
        Log.d("inside the coroutine ${count}")
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.kt

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {

    var counter = mutableStateListOf<Int>()

    fun increaseCounter() {
        Log.d(">>>", "in viewmodel ${counter.size}")
        counter.add(1)
    }
}
```

Desired Result:
Whenever i click on the button the log has to printed because it adds a number in the mutableStateList.

But when i change the mutableStateListOf into mutableStateOf and store some integer and change the integer the view gets recomposes and prints the log when i click on the button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem of your function not recomposing, is that you're not using the value for the view itself, so Compose caches it. If you add `Text(count.joinToString { it.to() })` to your view, it'll will work.

---

But first of all you shouldn't use coroutines directly from composable functions. And adding `@SuppressLint("CoroutineCreationDuringComposition")` is not the correct solution to the error IDE shows to you:

> Calls to launch should happen inside a [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#LaunchedEffect(kotlin.Any,kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)) and not composition

So instead your code should look like this:

```
@Composable
fun CountView(count: List<Int>) {
    LaunchedEffect(count) {
        println("inside the coroutine $count")
    }
}
```

This will also not work in your case, because with `mutableStateListOf`, `LaunchedEffect` compares key by pointer, and as this is still the same container, `LaunchedEffect` will not be relaunched. To compare by references it's cleaner to pass a plain list:

```
CountView(viewModel.counter.toList())
```

Note that inside [`LaunchedEffect`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#LaunchedEffect(kotlin.Any,kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)) you're already inside coroutine scope and can run suspend functions.

`rememberCoroutineScope` is usually used when you need to launch a coroutine from other side effects, like button click.

Read move about side effects in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects)

Comment: but .toList() will take extra O(n) timing right?... is there any other better ways?

Comment: @Venkataramanan As I said, if you'll use array values with views(which is usual thing), you won't need to convert to list. `LaunchedEffect` is gonna calculate hash and it'll take `O(n)` anyway. Otherwise, if you don't need that data for the view, and only for a side effect, consider adding some other variable which make sure the view updated, like a counter which will increase each time you update the data.